# How can I sign in with my fingerprint on Elementary OS 6 Odin?

Tags: greeter, pantheon, security

I have a fingerprint sensor supported by libfprint. How can I use it to log in to Elementary OS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Elementary OS greeter has support for fprintd via [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_PAM).

First, install the required packages:

```
sudo apt install libpam-fprintd
```

Next, start `fprintd` if it's not yet started:

```
sudo systemctl start fprintd
```

Then, enroll a fingerprint:

```
fprintd-enroll
```

Finally, enable the `fprintd` PAM module:

```
sudo pam-auth-update --enable fprintd
```

A fingerprint icon will now show up on the login screen, indicating that the sensor is active.

Comment: Many Dell laptops with Goodix sensors can use Dell's driver as well. Simply install the driver package along with `fprintd`: http://dell.archive.canonical.com/pool/public/libf/libfprint-2-tod1-goodix/

Comment: Enrolling right-index-finger finger.
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-stage-passed
Enroll result: enroll-disconnected que podria ser esto??