# Fingerprint driver

Tags: drivers

I have a problem with installing a fingerprint, I did everything that was in the solution of this article: [How can I sign in with my fingerprint on Elementary OS 6 Odin?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/28318/how-can-i-sign-in-with-my-fingerprint-on-elementary-os-6-odin)
But `fprintd-enroll` an error `Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available`

There is a driver for ubuntu 18.04 .rar on the manufacturer's website, how can I install them if they fit or how can I install other compatible drivers?

I tried to do everything that was indicated in the readme, but there was an error with the ppa connection, apparently the drivers for ubuntu 18 and 20 are incompatible

Comment: Can you post more details about your fingerprint reader device?